# bootstrap editable rails type select has empty results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the type =  select with the gem 'bootstrap-editable-rails'.

The field pops up and there is a select box, but the values don't show up.

The Task record has a foreign key = rating_id and the value I want to show from the rating table is = ratingname

This is my view code:

```
<a href="#" class="answer" data-type="select" data-placement="right"  data-resource="task" data-source="/ratings" data-name="ratingname" data-url="/tasks/<%= task.id %>" data-original-title="Select Rating">
  <%= textarea_format(task.rating.ratingname) %>
</a>
```

UPDATE 1

Do I have to change the ratings.json to contain "text" and "value"?

UPDATE 2

I used RABL like this:

```
object @rating
attributes :id => :id, :ratingname => :text, :ratingvalue => :value
```

And now the selection values show up!

But, I get this error:

```
`call'
(gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
- (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
- (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
- (gem) rack-pjax-0.7.0/lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
- (gem) meta_request-0.2.2/lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:11:in `call'
- (gem) rack-contrib-1.1.0/lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
- (gem) meta_request-0.2.2/lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
- (gem) meta_request-0.2.2/lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
- (gem) pdfkit-0.5.3/lib/pdfkit/middleware.rb:16:in `call'
- (gem) warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
- (gem) warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
- (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
- (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
- (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
- (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
- (gem) remotipart-1.0.5/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:30:in `call'
- (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
- (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
- (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
- (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
- (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
- (gem) activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'

...
```

UPDATE 3

I've almost got it to work.

My RABL:

```
object @rating
attributes :ratingname => :text, :id => :value
```

I get the ratingname as the dropdown list !
I have the following happen when a value is selected !!

```
UPDATE "tasks" SET "rating_id" = 2, "updated_at" = '2013-03-28 08:21:36.869872' WHERE "tasks"."id" = 36
```

So, the dropdown list is good, the update is good.

BUT, the popup box with the rating select list turns red and doesn't go away!  And there are no errors in the browser console.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.  I had to change the controller for tasks in the update section.

```
From:     format.json { head :ok }
To:       format.json { render json: @task }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you may got js conflicts ,so check for console

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'value' in undefined**

solution: use it inline as

**$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';**